# For bold to 700 for normal to 400 when minify css

Tags: css, performance, minify

When I minify my css with online css tool for example https://csscompressor.net/, tool convert font-weight:bold to font-weight:700; , font-weight:normal to font-weight:400; why?700 or 400 usage for high performance?

Comment: Probably because it saves a character? You are using a compressor after all...

Comment: "bold" => 4 characters, "700" => 3 characters. "normal" => 6 characters, "400" => 3 characters. MINIFIED!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In css, the `font-weight` property is a 9-point numeric scale from 100 to 900.

As a convenience, the special names `normal` and `bold` are defined, and are given the values 400 and 700.

(Other text values `inherit`, `bolder`, and `lighter` are calculated from the weight of the parent element as "same as parent", "next higher value from list `100, 400, 700, 900`" and "next lower value from list `100, 400, 700, 900`")

For more details, the spec is at http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/fonts.html#font-boldness

(So, when you write `font-weight:bold`, you really mean `font-weight:700`, and as the comments point out, the latter is one character shorter and so more "minimal"...)